# How to link build version with manual tests in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, azure-functions, test-plan

I have created the Test Plan, and we have a Pipeline to build our app. Are there any possibilities to link build version with Test run?

**My goal is to check which manual tests were executed for this build.**

What I found:

I know that we can run a test using option *Run with options* and then choose *Manual tests using Web Browser based runner*

[image]

Then, in section *Runs* we can check which Test Execution is linked to build number.

[image]

But are there any possibilities to check which tests are linked to the build? **In the build view we see just only result of auto tests**?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the build view we see just only result of auto tests?

As far as I know, if tests were executed as part of the build, the test result will exists in the `Pipeline Test tab` (e.g. run auto test with vstest task).

> Are there any possibilities to check which tests are linked to the build?

You could use Rest API to achieve this requirement.

Rest Api Uri:

```
Get https://dev.azure.com/{Organizaiton}/{Project}/_apis/test/runs?builduri=vstfs:///Build/Build/{Buildid}&includeRunDetails=true&api-version=5.1
```

Then you could get all the test runs (Manual and Automated) linked to the target build.

Here is a doc about the [Rest API - List Test Runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#general-example).

Hope this helps.